Case - Send Copy of an Activity template not auto generating Text version for copy activity details
When sending email notification based on activity type, the copy activity does not save or have a "details"/Notes value. Before, it was automatically generated. It would have something like this. I think it is based on the HTML Content of the template, but just automatically converted or similar.
===========================================================
Activity Summary - ...
===========================================================


Appears to have stopped working some time after 5.65 but before 5.74. Have made a lab ticket: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5629

@Demerit Thank you!

Have put up a potential fix at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/31572/files. It's just a one-line change in CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php line 1425. Change
$activityParams['details'] = $message;
to
$activityParams['details'] = $html;
This causes it to file html instead of text, but that seemed preferable anyway.

@david Can you comment on the PR that it fixes it? It will help get it merged.
